# How to measure italic font overhang in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, typography

I need to calculate italic text overhang in javascript. Here you can find picture what it means: [ms knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74298). I used the following link in order to calculate text width:
[Calculate text width with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top).
I added mock div and measured text width, but the problem is that last symbol is sloped and if I use text width for right alignment last symbol upper part is outside of the desired box. **I wonder** if it's possible to **calculate italic text angle of slope** or the **distance of the overhang** in order to subtract this value and to get my text properly aligned in the box?

Comment: Seems like it equals 0.25em. http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/548616-preventing-italics-text-hitting-next-character But I haven't found another proofs yet.